# in qtXml library, why qt use qhash to store xml element attributes Instead of QMap?

Tags: qt

I am using `qtxml` to write a xml file, I found that the output xml file's element attributes has different order each time I run my program.

I read the source code and found that `qtxml` use `QHash` to store element attributes, which will lead to output XML file's element attributes has different order each time I run my program.

Why not use `QMap` to store elements' attributes? which will produce an ordered attribute.

What's the difference between `QHash` and `QMap` in this scenario?

Comment: Why do you need attributes to have a specific order? XML format doesn't seem to specify any. QHash should work faster than QMap.

Comment: I'm using qt binarycreator to generate a binary file, the tmp file 'Update.xml' will cause my output binary file has different md5sum each time.  the reason is that qtxml use qhash to store element attributes.  I expect to output  a completely same binary file if i doesn't change my code.  @vahancho

Answer (score 0):

`QMap` is a Red-black tree.
`QHash` is implemented using a hash table

`QMap` is slower than `QHash`. `QMap` searches are faster than `QHash` with fewer than 10 items.

```
#include <QtCore/QtCore>
#include <unordered_map>
#ifndef CONTAINER
#error CONTAINER must be defined to QMap, QHash, std::map or std::unordered_map
#endif
namespace std {
/* std::hash specialization for QString so it can be used
* as a key in std::unordered_map */
template <class Key>
struct hash;
template <>
struct hash<QString> {
    typedef QString Key;
    typedef uint result_type;
    inline uint operator()(const QString& s) const { return qHash(s); }
};
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
        qFatal("" Missing number of element to add "");
    QByteArray a = argv[1];
    uint num = a.toUInt();
    // creates an array of random keys
    QVector<QString> strs(num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
        strs[i] = qvariant_cast<QString>(qrand());
    CONTAINER<QString, QString> c;
    for (uint i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        QString& k = strs[i];
        c[k] = QString::number(i);
    }
    quint64 it = 0;
    const QString* arr = strs.constData();
    QElapsedTimer t;
    t.start();
    while (t.elapsed() < 1000) {
        const QString& k = arr[(++it) * 797 % num];
        c[k]; // perform a lookup
    }
    qDebug() << it / 1000;
}
```

[image]

The higher the iteration value, the best. The scale of the number of elements is logarithmic. It should be expected that for `QHash` the value will not change with increasing number of elements, and for `QMap` it should be equal to log N, which corresponds to a straight line on a logarithmic scale.

However, with a large number of elements, the results are not in favor of QMap.
This is most likely the reason why QHash is used.